# div size to cover 80% of window display

Tags: html, css

How to set my first div to full window size.By implying these below code it is showing me 40% covered from top to bottom, but i want to set its div size to cover at least 80% from top to bottom.Which Css property I need to imply in Css.

HTML
    
    
    
    
    My page 
    HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
 </head>    
<body>


<div id="a">

    <div id="t" class="d"></div>

    <div id="p" class="c"></div>

    <div id="t" class="e"></div>


</div>
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="third"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
 #first, #second,#third{
    width: 100%;
 }


#a{

    background:url('images/rc1.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    height: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 160px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
     perspective: 1px;

}

#second{

    background:url('images/ra1.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 160px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
     perspective: 1px;

}
#third{

    background:url('images/rc11.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 160px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
     perspective: 1px;

}
.d{
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
    width:=218px;
    height: 73px;
    left: auto;
    top: 10%;
    background: url('images/Logo.png') top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x:50px;

}
.c{
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
    width: =774px;
    height: 209px;
    left: auto;
    top: 120%;
    /*width:=137px;
    height:88px;*/
    background: url('images/big_text.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x:339px;
}
.e{
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
    width: =127px;
    height: 37px;
    left:auto;
    top: 180%;
    background: url('images/scroll_text.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 680px;
}
```

Comment: `min-height: 100vh; min-width: 100%;`

Comment: where i need to put these property I applied on #a in my css its not making any change.

Comment: is this `background-position-x: 680px;` working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mix of % and vh:

HTML:

```
<div>
</div>
```

And do not forget to set your page using *:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div{
background: red; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100vh;
}
```

It will cover the whole window non matter its size

Comment: @dippune1 - Use the * on top of your CSS file and set paddings and margins to 0 to avoid blank spaces on your page

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 // for height
 $("#a").height($( window ).height() - 100 ); // minus any value in pixel 

 // for width
 $("#a").width($(window).width());

});


</script>
```

Comment: thanks but I don't want to use jquery it can be done through css that is what I looking for.